# using directadmin resetting counter in counter.pl script running on website

Tags: perl

my client side has counter.pl script running on homepage. that displays visitors counter
the client wants to change the visitor counter value.

when i checked the code in index.html,it points cgi-bin/counter.pl script
But wen i try to search cg-bin folder ther are only two files counter.jpg and .htaccess

now how to find the counter.pl script and edit ...!!!??

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

Check the web server configuration to see where the `cgi-bin` directory really is. If you're using apache then you want to look for something like this:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/
```

in the `httpd.conf` and related files. The actual `cgi-bin` directory is often located somewhere outside the DocumentRoot directory.

Comment: thanks for reply.    cgi-bin directory is ther but inside cg-bin directory  counter.pl script is not ther. only counter.jpg file there

Comment: Then that's not the right cgi-bin directory. If you're using apache then look in the httpd.conf file for a ScriptAlias directive, that will tell you where the cgi-bin directory that the server is using is. I don't know how other servers handle their configurations. Just because you found a directory called "cgi-bin" doesn't mean that you're looking in the right place.